# Change Set-Cookie Path in Azure APIM response

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have been trying to change the cookie path of my Azure APIM API response. The response from the APIM looks like this `Set-Cookie: ssnid=2d4cfdd62638436481130eb0fad7a889; path=/; secure; HttpOnly`. I checked the transform policies available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/transform-api) but still haven't figured out a solution.

Comment: you mean you want it to be `889; path=/myNewPath/foo; secure;`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to change the cookie path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't run this but this should generally work:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <set-header name="Set-Cookie" exists-action="override">
            <value>@{
               var cookie = context.Response.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Set-Cookie","");
               return cookie.Replace("path=/;", "path=/myNewPath;");
            }
            </value>
        </set-header>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```